# discovery.build call causing python to stop working

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I have been working on a script to upload a .csv file to google drive. The script was working throughout the day except recently it has been crashing/ causing python to stop working. It seems to crash when I call:

```
service = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=http)
```

Here is the main function from the script:

```
def main():
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=http)
    #upload to Reload Folder
    folder_id = 'RealIdExcluded'
    file_metadata = {
        'name': 'allStats.csv',
        'mimeType' : 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet' 
    }

    media = MediaFileUpload('statOutput.csv',
                            mimetype = 'text/csv',
                            resumable = True)
    file = service.files().update(body= file_metadata,
                                    media_body=media,
                                    fields = 'id',
                                    fileId = 'RealIdExcluded').execute()
    print('File ID: %s' % file.get('id'))
```

Any help be awesome. Thanks

Comment: I never figured out what the problem was, but I uninstalled python and reinstalled which seemed to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I never figured out what the problem was, but I uninstalled python and reinstalled which seemed to fix the issue.